# Is there any windows API available through which i can register for events on remote machines and remote machine responds on event occurence?

Tags: windows, api, events

I want an windows api which can register to events occuring on remote machine. whenever event occurs remote machine will callback.
Remote events examples-  new user accout creation on remote machine. 
Suggest any possible solution.

Comment: I am not really familiar with the specifics but WMI may be an option.

Comment: Hey,Luke Thanks for considering my question. i got answer, i have posted that below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window has one service called as

```
Windows event collector
```

through wich we can forward or receive event logs from remote computer in the same domain. we can also specify which kind of event we want to moniter. this is available with windows vista onwards.